# Why is javascript not part of the project architecture?

Tags: php, javascript, lamp

I recently came across a question where someone asked what architecture we use in the company and someone else replied LAMP.

I am not sure why we do not include javascript as a part of the architecture. Is it implied? Or is there something I am missing? What if someone is using say ECMA script or VB script instead of javascript?

Comment: My guess is that adding a J to LAMP would not sound cool no matter where it's placed.

Comment: That someone in the company just happened to include only server side in the "architecture". A matter of choice really imo. Also your question is not right - "Why is javascript not part of LAMP? Because LAMP is linux-apache-mysql-php." Maybe the question should be "Why is javascript not part of the project architecture?".

Comment: @JP19 - you are correct .. done..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because "LAMP" only addresses the technologies that run on the server-side, not what runs on the client-side, like the browser, or JavaScript within the browser. (And at the time "LAMP" was coined, JavaScript saw much less usage than it does today.)

Comment: +1... i agree with the differentiation, but shouldn't it be a part of the architecture of the project?

Comment: @pinaki: LAMP is not a project architecture so much as it is specifically a server software architecture. With that said, if JavaScript is involved in the frontend development of your web project, why not?

Comment: It's considered part of the architecture these days, you know, "AJAX", it just hasn't become part of the acronym.

Comment: hmmm... makes sense.. so, would you say LAMP plus javascript when someone asks you the project architecture???

Comment: Well, I'm not a huge fan of MySQL, nor PHP, but yes, typically some level of "rich client interaction" is implied. jQuery being somewhat of a default, but no means only, choice.

Comment: allright.. accepting  the answer on the implied note then... also one fair point from comments is that it's a matter of opinion if someone includes client side languages intot the architecture or not... thanks for the replies everyone..

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript is a client-side technology, while Linux, Apache, MySQL and Perl/Python/PHP all have to do with the server.

There are server-side JavaScript implementations like [Aptana Jaxer](http://jaxer.org) and [node.js](http://nodejs.org), but JavaScript is most commonly-used for browser behavior, and thus doesn't have much to do with the server other than through Ajax requests.

Comment: +1... you rightly mention ajax which is again triggered by javascript. So any reasons for not including it in the architectural languages?? why humuliate it :-)....

Comment: @pinaki: Like I said, the acronym itself refers to only the server. Ajax is still largely a client-side technology, because Ajax is used to interact with the server and the data that it has to provide. The application server often doesn't care if a request is an Ajax request, it just serves data as needed.

Answer (score 0):

LAMP refers to the major technologies used on the server side: Linux, Apache, MySQL, and PHP. There are many other pieces to a LAMP installation, but they are either of minor importance (such as the bash shell) or are client-side: HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and so forth.

Comment: PHP? P'toiee (sound of me spitting out something 'orrible). Give me my beloved Python version any day, or even Perl if you must :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: I just added both to my answer if it makes you happy :)

Answer (score 0):

LAMP is the server architecture.

On the web, it's very much assumed that HTML, JavaScript and CSS comprise the client architecture.

Also, JavaScript is a dialect of ECMAScript with web-browser specific modifications.

Comment: You mean comprise, not compromise :)

Comment: Actually, I rather liked "HTML, JavaScript and CSS _compromise_ the client architecture" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a web based client side technology. It can be enabled or disabled by the user.